# Identifying Grails plugin using old Hibernate version

Tags: grails

Having updated my Grails app from Hibernate 2.2.4 to 2.2.5, I now get the following every time I run 'grails war':

You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [hibernate-2.2.5]. Do you want to update to [hibernate-2.2.4]? [y,n]

I understand that this is probably because of some requirement in a plugin I'm using, and the normal advice is to run 'grails dependency-report'. I've done that but I'm unsure how to interpret the result and take the necessary action to update the dependency. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running a `grails clean` and `grails refresh-dependencies`?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Did a `grails clean` but not a `grails refresh-dependencies`. But the problem was resolved yesterday when I upgraded the Shiro plugin to 1.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

My problem seems to have been to do with having Shiro plugin version 1.2.0 installed. When I updated to 1.2.1, the issue with the Hibernate version was resolved.

Comment: To the future cases, in the modern Grails version you may use `grails dependency-report` to find and resolve that troubles.